# How to print actual shortest path Dijkastra Python

Tags: python, shortest-path

I am an adventofcode solver, and I have a my solution using Dijkastra in Python (see attached code). I have successfully calculated how many steps it takes to get to letter "E". The solution for a sample data was 31.

My solution:
https://github.com/xjantoth/aoc2022/blob/main/day12/solution.py

Riddle: https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/12

Input data

```
Sabqponm
abcryxxl
accszExk
acctuvwj
abdefghi
```

One thin which is not clear to me (since it is a first time I have used this algorithm) is how to print actual shortest path. It is definitely not a "buffer", neither the "seen" variable I have used. So how to print this 31 coordinates which represent shortest path in Dijkastra ? Thx

Any ideas

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import deque

data = [line for line in open(0).read().splitlines()]
m = {"S": "a", "E": "z"}

E = 0 + 0j
S = 0 + 0j
co = {}

for y, d in enumerate(data):
    for x, i in enumerate(d):
        if i == "E":
            E = x + y*1j
        if i == "S":
            S = x + y*1j
        co[(x + y*1j)] = [m.get(i, i), ord(m.get(i, i))]


def dfs(grid, start, end):
    buffer = deque([(start, 0)])
    seen = set()

    while buffer:
        current = buffer.popleft()
        if current[0] in seen:
            continue

        # Part 1
        if current[0] == end:
            return current[1], seen, len(seen)

        seen.add(current[0])

        neighbours = [
            current[0] + (-1 + 0j),
            current[0] + (1 + 0j),
            current[0] + (0 + -1j),
            current[0] + (0 + 1j)
        ]
        for n in neighbours:
            if n.real < 0 or n.imag < 0 or n.real >= len(data[0]) or n.imag >= len(data):
                #print(n)
                continue
            if grid[n][1] <= grid[current[0]][1] + 1:

                buffer.append((n, current[1]+1))
    return False

print(dfs(co, S, E)[0])
```

Comment: You must keep track of the steps leading to your current solution as you move through the algorithmic solution.

Comment: Hm, I keep track of seen but how to to track these particular steps ? can you suggest ?

Comment: Keep a list of visited places as you move forward

Comment: well that is tracked in seen - but this variable holds more steps, than the actual answer.

Comment: Seen tracks all nodes visited.  To maintain the path followed, you need to add a variable that keeps a list of the nodes visited as you move through the network, so that when you reach the end, you can output the path traveled.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by my comment, to record the path traveled, I would update the dfs function to record the path as follows:

```
def dfs(grid, start, end):
    buffer = deque()
    buffer.append([start, end, []]) # added list of nodes traveled
    seen = set()

    while buffer:
        current = buffer.popleft()
        if current[0] in seen:
            continue

        # Part 1
        if current[0] == end:
            return current[1], seen, len(seen), current[2]

        seen.add(current[0])
        current[2].append(current[0])  # Update path traveled

        neighbours = [
                      current[0] + (-1 + 0j),
                      current[0] + (1 + 0j),
                      current[0] + (0 + -1j),
                      current[0] + (0 + 1j)
                      ]
        for n in neighbours:
            if n.real < 0 or n.imag < 0 or n.real >= len(data[0]) or n.imag >= len(data):
                #print(n)
                continue
            if grid[n][1] <= grid[current[0]][1] + 1:
                buffer.append([n, current[1]+1, current[2]])
                              
    return False
```